# Displaying rtmp live stream video in Cesium?

Tags: cesium

I would like to display an rtmp stream video in Cesium. I created an entity and used the `<video>` element as its material. When I use video stored locally (in .mp4 format) it worked fine, but when I switched to an rtmp source and play it via videojs, it can play in `<video>` element, but it can't play on the entity. The rtmp uses flash to play, while ordinary video does not require flash, I wonder if its because of this.

Here's the `<video>` element

```html
<video id="rtmpStream" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="300" data-setup="{}" autoplay>
        <source src="rtmp://202.69.69.180:443/webcast/bshdlive-pc" type="rtmp/flv">
    </video>
```

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957205/html5-video-tag-rtmp-streaming-without-flash

Comment: Cross-posted to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57473544/is-it-possible-to-display-rtmp-live-stream-video-in-cesium